# What does an equal sign mean in a parenthesis?

Tags: notation

I'm now learning about Reinforcement Learning and in the Bellman equation, there is a following equal sign.

[image]

I understand the meaning of the left side of the equation, which is *the probability of transitioning from state s to state s' with action a*. However on the right side, what does the `=` sign mean?

The `pr` likely means the probability (but then why does it not use `P`?), and the `|` means *given the condition of the right side*, right? But I don't understand what the equal sign here means, and why is needed... IOW, what makes it different from `pr(s_t+1 | s_t, a_t)`?

Comment: Learn probability first

Comment: By all means, do what @GuySa suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The right hand side would be read:

"The conditional probability that $s_{t+1}$ is equal to $s'$ given that the value of $s_t$ is equal to $s$ and that the value of $a_t$ is equal to $a$."

Answer (score 1):

It means the probability that the state at time $t+1$ is $s'$ given that the state and action at time $t$ are $s$ and $a$.